# How to download data from Carrier data/3GS not wifi?

Tags: iphone, wifi, nsurlconnection, carrier

In my iphone app, the user can set whether he wants to download data from internet via wifi or 3G/Carrier data.

How can we do that programatically?

In other words, how can I force iphone to get data from carrier data not from wifi?

Any suggestion guys?

Comment: Why do you want to force someone to use carrier data and not WiFi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't force the iPhone to use carrier data (3G / Edge) instead of WiFi if the phone is connected to WiFi. You can use the [SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/SCNetworkReachabilityRef/Reference/reference.html) function to determine if you're on WiFi or have a carrier data connection.

What you could do is, if the user is connected to WiFi, pop up a message saying that your app only works with carrier data and ask the user to switch off WiFi and restart the app. I would not recommend this though as it will just irritate the hell out of your users, although this didn't stop Vodafone Portugal from doing it for a number of their apps in a silly attempt to force you to use more (expensive) carrier data.

Answer (score 3):

You can't, if the iPhone is connect to WiFi you can not programmaticly force it to use the cellular network to download.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is helpful to you:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 1):

For that you need to detect the state of the phone and you can easily identifies the weather data isn't transfer when a phone uses the wifi.

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // check for internet connection

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkNetworkStatus:)  name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];

    internetReachable = [[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] retain];        

    [internetReachable startNotifier];        

    // check if a pathway to a random host exists        

    hostReachable = [[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName: @"www.apple.com"]  retain];

     [hostReachable startNotifier];        

    // now patiently wait for the notification

}



- (void) checkNetworkStatus:(NSNotification *)notice     {      

    // called after network status changes     

    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [internetReachable currentReachabilityStatus];
    switch (internetStatus){
        case NotReachable:
            {
                NSLog(@"The internet is down.");
                self.internetActive = NO;
                 break;
            }
            case ReachableViaWiFi:
            {
                NSLog(@"The internet is working via WIFI.");
                self.internetActive = YES;
                break;
            }
            case ReachableViaWWAN:
            {
                NSLog(@"The internet is working via WWAN.");
                self.internetActive = YES;
                break;
            }
        }
        NetworkStatus hostStatus = [hostReachable currentReachabilityStatus];
        switch (hostStatus)
        {
            case NotReachable:
            {
                NSLog(@"A gateway to the host server is down.");
                self.hostActive = NO;
                break;
            }
            case ReachableViaWiFi:
            {
                NSLog(@"A gateway to the host server is working via WIFI.");
                self.hostActive = YES;
                break;
            }
            case ReachableViaWWAN:
            {
                NSLog(@"A gateway to the host server is working via WWAN.");
                self.hostActive = YES;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

[more information visits this link.](http://sugartin.info/2011/08/01/detecting-network-status/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but this was not a question actually. Anyways Great effort :)